# How to Find or Message someone by their Telegram numerical user ID?

Tags: api, bots, telegram, profile, userid

So here is my situation, I had about 8000 users in Telegram message my bot but Unfortunately I did not know I had to save their chat IDs, instead I saved their User IDs which is the numerical one like 123456789

Now what are the options that I have to contact those people again ? even having a way to access their profile by their User ID would be good (Granting they did not block the bot)